# Define and declare of variable of C question

Tags: c

I have a question about define and declare variables.
I defined pi as 3.14 and wanted to see its address, but

```
    printf("address of pi is %d\n", &pi);
```

This line gives an error.
which is kind of weird because

```
    printf("address of pi is %.2f\n", pi);
```

this line prints 3.14.
Does this mean that defining pi does not allocate memory location to pi?
then how can where is that 3.14 coming from?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define pi 3.14

int main(){
    
    printf("address of pi is %.2f\n", pi);
    printf("address of pi is %d\n", &pi);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Display the preprorcessed file to see how the macros (i.e. #define) operate. If your source file is called program.c and you are using gcc: gcc -E program.c

Answer (score 4):

A `#define` macro does a direct text / token substitution.  So after the preprocessor run, this:

```
printf("address of pi is %d\n", &pi);
```

Gets turned into this:

```
printf("address of pi is %d\n", &3.14);
```

So you're actually trying to get the address of a numeric constant which is invalid.

Had you declared `pi` as a variable, i.e.:

```
float pi = 3.14;
```

Then you could get its address.

Also, you should use `%p` to print the address of a variable, not `%d`, and you need to cast the address to `void *`.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. So when we use #define macro preprocessor directly substitute pi to 3.14 in objective code? therefore, from the CPU point of view, it is not asked to get the data 3.14 from memory, while when we declare pi as a variable, from the CPU point of view, it has to access a given address to get the data.

Comment: @TrueRoughly Roughly speaking, yes.

Answer (score 0):

#define is used for constants. It is a preprocessor instruction.
So the value is defined when you are compiling and is not allocated.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to assign a value to a variable, you have to declare the variable and assign the value like this:

```
float pi=3.14;
pi=0.0001;
```

Whenever you declare a variable, the needed amount of memory is assigned automatically.

On the other hand, &pi does not express the contents of variable pi, but the adress where the contents of the variable are stored into.
So, the right code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float pi=3.14;    
    printf("address of pi is %.2f\n", pi);
   
    return 0;

}
```